# Data Cleaning w/ Pandas: Replacing "(2.34M)" to "-2340000" (convert negative number in brackets w/ magnitude symbol to float/integer without brackets)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following datasets:

[image]

As you can see, the "cash dividends paid" for 2016 is (2.36B).
Which actually means -2360 000 000 as integer.
B stands for billion and M million.

How could I replace the formating without using "loopy" methode?
Preferably using pandas (and, not sure, regex).

Thank you for any guidance:-)

Comment: If you included your dataset as a CSV or something else people can copy-and-paste into a Python environment, instead of a screenshot, you'd be much more likely to get some help. And ideally include some sample code indicating what you've tried so far, and why it isn't working.

Comment: *"Thank you for any guidance:-)"* - Since you asked ... I would just like to point out that *in context* 2.36B probably means a number in the range 2,350,000,000 to 2,364,999,999.  Probably.  But it is definitely not the exact number that you say it is.  This should affect the way that you use the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit (New Solution):

Simplified algorithm:

Let's use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with regex together with [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) function:

```
# regex patterns for converting text to floating point exponential notation 
pattern = {'\((.*)\)': '-\\1',    # convert (x) to -x
           'B': 'e+09',           # convert B to 'e+09' (equivalent to '* 1000000000')
           'M': 'e+06',           # convert M to 'e+06' (equivalent to '* 1000000')
           'K': 'e+03',           # convert K to 'e+03' (equivalent to '* 1000')
           '\s': ''               # remove white space, if any
          }

# replace with regex patterns and convert to floating point numbers
df = df.replace(pattern, regex=True).astype(float)
```

Same as the old solution, the new logics does not assume the numeric part of text is of any specific number of decimal point digits.  It can convert the amounts to correct magnitudes as long as the numeric parts are valid integers or floating points numbers.

Optionally, if your data does not contain `NaN` and you are sure the numbers have no fractional values (non-zero decimal point values), you can further convert the floating point numbers to integers by replacing the last line of codes to:

```
df = df.replace(pattern, regex=True).astype(float).astype(int)
```

### Demo Run

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'cash_dividend': ['(2.36B)', np.nan, '(1.92 M)', '(328K)', '216.04 M'], 
        'repurchase': ['(81.84M)', '(1.92M)', np.nan, '(10.13 M)', '(1.14B)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
print(df)
    
  cash_dividend repurchase
0       (2.36B)   (81.84M)
1           NaN    (1.92M)
2      (1.92 M)        NaN
3        (328K)  (10.13 M)
4      216.04 M    (1.14B)
    
# regex patterns for converting text to floating point exponential notation 
pattern = {'\((.*)\)': '-\\1',    # convert (x) to -x
           'B': 'e+09',           # convert B to 'e+09' (equivalent to '* 1000000000')
           'M': 'e+06',           # convert M to 'e+06' (equivalent to '* 1000000')
           'K': 'e+03',           # convert K to 'e+03' (equivalent to '* 1000')
           '\s': ''               # remove white space, if any
          }
    
# replace with regex pattern
df = df.replace(pattern, regex=True)
   
Output:  
# values converted to float values (in string) with correct magnitudes. 
# Negative numbers in brackets e.g (x), also converted to -x
    
  cash_dividend  repurchase
0     -2.36e+09  -81.84e+06
1           NaN   -1.92e+06
2     -1.92e+06         NaN
3      -328e+03  -10.13e+06
4    216.04e+06   -1.14e+09

print(df.dtypes)               # check data types

cash_dividend    object        <=== string type
repurchase       object        <=== string type
dtype: object

df = df.astype(float)   # convert to floating point data type
    
print(df)
    
Output: # float values (in string) converted to real float number data type 
    
   cash_dividend    repurchase
0  -2.360000e+09 -8.184000e+07
1            NaN -1.920000e+06
2  -1.920000e+06           NaN
3  -3.280000e+05 -1.013000e+07
4   2.160400e+08 -1.140000e+09

print(df.dtypes)               # check data types

cash_dividend    float64       <=== float type
repurchase       float64       <=== float type
dtype: object
```

### Old Solution:

Let's use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with regex together with [`df.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) + [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) function:

```
# regex patterns for converting text to calculation formula  
pattern = {'\((.*)\)': '-\\1',    # convert (x) to -x
           'B': ' * 1000000000',  # convert B to ' * 1000000000'
           'M': ' * 1000000',     # convert M to ' * 1000000'
           'K': ' * 1000'         # convert K to ' * 1000'
          }

# replace with regex patterns and evaluate formulae with pd.eval()
df = df.replace(pattern, regex=True).applymap(pd.eval, na_action='ignore')
```

The logics does not assume the numeric part of text is of any specific number of decimal point digits.  It can convert the amounts to correct magnitudes as long as the numeric parts are valid integers or floating points numbers.

The first part of the pattern is making use of 2 features of regex to achieve conversion of (x) to -x:

1. [*Capturing group*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html):  Used in the first half of the first line, i.e.  `'\((.*)\)'` With brackets `(...)` around `.*`, we are capturing those within `\(` and `\)` into **capturing group number 1.**  Thus, for `(2.36B)`, we capture `2.36B` into capturing group number 1.
2. [*Back-referencing*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html):  Used in the 2nd half of the first line, i.e. `'-\\1'`  By using regex `\1` we are referencing to what's captured in **capturing group number 1**.  (So, if we have more than 1 pair of brackets in the first part, we can use `\2` for the 2nd capturing group.)  We need an extra `\` before `\1` to escape the special symbol `\` in `\1`.  (We can save this extra `\` if we use `r'-\1'` instead with raw-string `r'....'`.)   So, overall we put a negative sign `-` before back referencing what's captured in the capturing group. Thus, we are making a replacement with `-2.36B` for `2.36B` captured previously in the capturing group.

### Demo Run

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'cash_dividend': ['(2.36B)', np.nan, '(1.92M)', '(328K)', '216.04M'], 
        'repurchase': ['(81.84M)', '(1.92M)', np.nan, '(10.13M)', '(1.14B)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

  cash_dividend repurchase
0       (2.36B)   (81.84M)
1           NaN    (1.92M)
2       (1.92M)        NaN
3        (328K)   (10.13M)
4       216.04M    (1.14B)

pattern = {'\((.*)\)': '-\\1',    # convert (x) to -x
           'B': ' * 1000000000',  # convert B to ' * 1000000000'
           'M': ' * 1000000',     # convert M to ' * 1000000'
           'K': ' * 1000'         # convert K to ' * 1000'
          }

# replace with regex pattern
df = df.replace(pattern, regex=True)

        cash_dividend          repurchase
0  -2.36 * 1000000000    -81.84 * 1000000
1                 NaN     -1.92 * 1000000
2     -1.92 * 1000000                 NaN
3         -328 * 1000    -10.13 * 1000000
4    216.04 * 1000000  -1.14 * 1000000000

df = df.applymap(pd.eval, na_action='ignore')     # evaluate formulae with pd.eval()

print(df)

Output:  # formulae converted to float values with correct magnitudes

   cash_dividend    repurchase
0  -2.360000e+09 -8.184000e+07
1            NaN -1.920000e+06
2  -1.920000e+06           NaN
3  -3.280000e+05 -1.013000e+07
4   2.160400e+08 -1.140000e+09
```

Comment: I like your solution. However, I can't understand the logic of "-\\1". If I only use the first pattern, I will get from "(2.36B)" an output of "-2.36B". How could Python know to get the value "2.36B" just with the "\\1"? I was looking for such possibility and now am getting it from you, but couldn't understand it. Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: @gunardilin,  See my edit above with explanation of the first part of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace using both `regex` and a dictionary to hold all your scenarios. Here is one example using a mock dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cash': ['1.2B', '(2.4M)', '3.2K'], 'dividends': ['0.8B', '(0.2K)', '1.2M']})

     cash dividends
0    1.2B      0.8B
1  (2.4M)    (0.2K)
2    3.2K      1.2M
```

Build a pattern mapping every desired occurrence to its replacement (I'm deliberately dropping a 0 from the units, so the conversion works properly):

```
pattern = {'B': '00000000', 'M': '00000', 'K': '00', '\.|\)': '', '\(': '-'}
new = df.replace(pattern, regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Output:

```
         cash  dividends
0  1200000000  800000000
1    -2400000       -200
2        3200    1200000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could us applymap - create a function ('fixer' in the example below) to 'sort out' a given cell, and use applymap to apply it to the entire dataframe. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 

test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

def fixer(cell):
    original = cell
    cell = cell.strip()
    multiplier = 1
    dirty = False
    # if there are brackets, make multiplier -1
    if "(" in cell and ")" in cell:
        multiplier = -1
        cell = cell.replace("(", "")
        cell = cell.replace(")", "")
        dirty = True

    if cell.endswith("B"):
        multiplier = 1000000000
        cell = cell[0:-1]
        dirty = True
    elif cell.strip().endswith("M"):
        multiplier = 1000000
        cell = cell[0:-1]
        dirty = True

    if dirty:
        val = float(cell) * multiplier
        return val
    else:
        return original

print(test)  
test = test.applymap(fixer)
print(test)
```